# RESTful webservice API : how to handle a web URI route for a 100 music files

Tags: web-services, rest

I am a totally newbie to the world of REST API. from what I have read and I think I understand 2 main things .

1) REST uses the the same HTTP methods (GET PUT etc) for a specific resource on the server.

2) Every resource on my server must be accessible from a unique URI.

So Combining 1 and 2, I can send a HTTP request to send a resource URI (eg. Radio.com/Music/1 and a GET request which will then fetch Music song 1).

Now I have a simple HTML page which has links to 100 Music files on the server. The idea is that the client will click on a link and then Should be able to play/download the music file (I am not so concerned about the how part related to audio). So the server must provide the links to each Music file eg: Radio.com/Music/1 .

My Question:
Q1) In this way must the should the client be exposed to each and every URI for the resource. So When the hosting the html page should i put these links individually for each music file link

Q2) We need to have a route to each and every resource for the 100 music files on the server . If I am  doing in Sinatra like do I need a do route for every of the 100 music files ?
Something link '/do' /Music/1 , '/do' /Music/2 and so on

(Isn't this cumbersome and if I add another 100 music files , then I need to add another 100 routes in Sinatra).

Is this how the REST API would work, or have I totally got it wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Imagine you have two servers.

1. First server is your api server: `http://api.yourhost.com/v1/...` (java, node.js, etc...)
   This REST-server will return a simple json response:

   ```
   {
   "base_url"  : "http://static.yourhost.com/music/",
   "tracks"    : [
           {
               "name" : "track1",
               "file_name" : "track1.mp3"
               "file_size" : "3.43MB"
           },
           {
               "name" : "track2",
               "file_name" : "track2.mp3"
               "file_size" : "6.12MB"
           }

           [...]
   ]
   }
   ```
2. The second server: `http://static.yourhost.com/` is your content delivery server (apache, nginx, etc...)

The idea is, that your *api REST server* should never send binary data like audio or image. It sends json/xml only.

You can also send the full url for every audio file, but this information could be redundant.

Comment: i am trying to understand the reason for this abstraction. Couldn't the same Apache server act the server where i have a .rb sinatra program (as CGI script) and also host all my web pages? Is that not possible ?

Comment: the reason is, you do not need to implement content delivery by `/Music/{id}`. just configure Apache or nginx to deliver media from `/home/web/Music` Also you can run one REST server and 10 File servers.

Comment: I was now planning to build a web app with a few html pages , audio,video and a dedicated API server that will return only JSON, however i am confused how an HTML page in a delivery server will consume an JSON sent back from an app server (like a Passenger server i am guessing) . Could you guide me to how to some pointers or tutorials on how the JSON objects are communicated and consumed by a html page on the separate content delivery server?

Comment: thanks for that, it was the direction i was looking for. Just to draw a picture in my simple head. Is the below flow correct?, Web Browser -> get (route) ->Apache server (web http server)-> Passenger (application with REST API returning JSON object (say X) only -> Apache server (with Jquery to consume the same JSON object X) and return the http response to client broswer.

Comment: and if this is correct, then how do i redirect to another html as i would be requesting to (abc.com/music) and expecting the that i get a a new html page (b.html) with the JSON response. but as per the above i am only getting back the JSON but nowhere specifying which HTML file should be going back to the client,

Comment: i was trying to get my head around this issue and thought i could use some sort of a reverse proxy in Apache to control what goes to Passenger , however i have a fundamental doubt i.e in Sinatra/passenger should we only send back JSON/XML responses and Apache send back html which will have a jquery to consume this JSON? or Should sinatra/passenger send back JSON consumed html ?

Comment: hm... it would be better if you start a new question. describe the full use case, so we can help you.

Comment: yes completely agreed , i have another one  [link] (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30147322/apache-with-passenger-for-static-html-pages) , which relates to who should give html pages

Comment: and the question pertaining exactly to the above scenario : [linkk (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30139933/rest-api-with-apache-http-web-content-server-sinatra-passenger-app-server) , thanks for all the help so far appreciate it

Answer (score 1):

**ad 1)**

> When the hosting the html page should i put these links individually for each music file link

If you take REST seriously and if you see this HTML page as a representation of the collection resource of *all* music files, you should do this. One basic mechanism of REST is links for the client. The client should be able to just follow links without having to build them himself.

**ad 2)**

> We need to have a route to each and every resource for the 100 music files on the server.

Every library that implements a RESTful server is able to have routes with *path paramters*. Usually such a route is defined using a pattern like

```
/Music/{id}
```

where `{id}` is the path parameter. The code that is bound to this route will then have available a variable named `id`. Using this approach you need only one route.