# Apache with Passenger for Static HTML Pages

Tags: apache, rest, passenger

I have a Sinatra app deployed on a Passenger server which is talking to Apache via Rack. I was wondering for the static pages if I need not go through the rack implementation as it would be a additional and necessary overhead to display static pages.

So is there a way i can put a condition to Apache to respond to certain URI directly with the static pages and for some to pass it to the Passenger API?

Is this possible via some configuration in Apache or does everything have to go via Rack?

Comment: Just to add current .conf file for my app looks like:<VirtualHost *:80>
    # ServerName [!! Your domain OR droplet's IP]
    ServerName 127.0.0.1 

    # !!! Be sure to point DocumentRoot to 'public'!
    # DocumentRoot [root to your app./public]
    DocumentRoot /home/anil/Masters/Software_Arch/SRHRadio/public

    # Directory [root to your app./public]
    <Directory /home/anil/Masters/Software_Arch/SRHRadio/public>
        # This relaxes Apache security settings.
        AllowOverride all
        # MultiViews must be turned off.
        Options -MultiViews
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>

Comment: Was thinking can this be done by using a reverse proxy in Apache?. Is this the correct way?. So i can specify a URL that can be passed onto Passenger and for all others i can allow Apache to respond back?. So Apache gives back all html,audio,video files etc and Passenger only sends back the JSON reponses.